# Regex to find filename from filename with size next to it. eg. "test.pdf ( 54 KB )"

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract `fileName` from string having `fileName` and `fileSize` (optional) using RegEx in C#.

Examples:

```
test.pdf ( 54 KB ) - fileName is test.pdf 
test.pdf - fileName is test.pdf
test.pdf (test) ( 54 KB) - fileName is test.pdf (test)
test.pdf (test) - fileName is test.pdf (test)
```

My attempt is given below

```
 string pattern = @"(.*)\s*\(\s\d+\sKB\s\)$";
 matches = Regex.Matches(fileName, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 actualFileName = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

But this is failing if the input doesn't have `fileSize` next to it.

Comment: Can I ask where the data actually comes from? `.pdf (test)` isn't a valid file extension so how is that a valid output?

Comment: @Sayse that was just an example.. it could be "test (test).pdf" which is a valid fileName

Comment: Yes but that drastically changes what answers could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `?` to make the first match non-greedy, and `?` to make the second part optional (different meaning and usage).

```
@"(.*?)\s*(?:\(\s*\d+\s*KB\s*\))?$"
```

Note the use of the `(?:)` non-capturing group around the size part, and the `?` after it that modifies the group to be optional.